# can a cPanel password change after a restoration of a full backup?

Tags: cpanel

I checked with my server if they could restore a full backup that I performed in another server, they told I should configure the FTP to use SSH, I did that, uploaded the file, they've restored everything, but as soon as I tried to change the cPanel password, I couldn't, I wasn't being able to login after the logout too.
So I talked to them and they had no idea of what happened. It's a brand new hosting account and the password was changed right after the restoration, and nobody knows who have changed it, so could it be the previous password from the old server that came with the full backup? I couldn't check that cause I asked them to reset the server password.

Comment: This question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as it is not about programming (and no, it doesn't).

Comment: Where should I post it?

Comment: Nowhere, this question isn't on-topic anywhere on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Well I can see a lot of questions here regarding cPanel.

Comment: The *programming* side of it, perhaps. Your question isn't about programming and so it doesn't belong here.

Comment: How can you be so sure it isn't about programming? Then why did the backup restoration changed the server pw? Magic?

Comment: Yes, but to ask a question here it needs to be about *your* code, not anybody else's.